# "an actress and a singer" or "an actress and singer"

Tags: appositives

> 1.Jennifer Lopez, an actresss and  singer, is playing tennis.
>
> 2.Jennifer Lopez, an actresss and a singer, is playing tennis.

I want to know whether the article is used once or twice for emphasis of a person's job.

Comment: No difference in meaning, but #1 is more common.

Answer (score 1):

To provide a little bit of background, I believe there is an instance of conjunction reduction in the second sentence. Omitting the 'a' is optional, and gets rid of repeated material in parallel clauses or phrases. Though I would say it's safer to keep the second article in some cases as repeation can often make for better flow and lead to less confusion.

In the context you provided however, I would say there is little difference between those two sentences, and most people will interpret them the same way. Whether you use the article once or twice is  entirely your choice :)

Hope it helped.

Answer (score -3):

#1 would imply two people playing tennis. 
#2 states she is both and she is playing tennis.

Comment: Please provide an explanation with every answer.